# How to shorten long python commands in console?

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that I start with

`python /home/USER/path/tagging.py -i /missions/YYYY/YYYYMMDD/HHMM/jpg -o /missions2/YYYY/YYYYMMDD/HHMM/jpg -l /missions/YYYY/YYYYMMDD/HHMM/info/*.bin`

I want to make a bash script for the bashrc that uses that exact command with:

`tagging YYYY/YYYYMMDD/HHMM`

because the only thing changing is YYYY/YYYYMMDD/HHMM

Any hint?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] yet?

Comment: I think this would be done by a bash function in your `~/bash_profile` folder. I would look into that if I were you.

Comment: In a bash script you can replace any string or substring (in general) with `$1` to get the first argument. Go forth and conquer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a bash script with arguments, you can access those arguments inside your script as [positional parameters](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html) `$1`, `$2`,.. where `$1` is the first argument, `$2` is the second argument, etc. (`$0` is special, it stores the script name).

You can then create a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

python /home/USER/path/tagging.py -i /missions/${1}/jpg -o /missions2/${1}/jpg -l /missions/${1}/info/*.bin
```

where all the `YYYY/YYYYMMDD/HHMM` is replaced by `${1}` that is expected to be passed to the script.

Then call it like this:

```
/path/to/tagging.sh YYYY/YYYYMMDD/HHMM
```

Comment: Note: You can also place this file on your PATH, and then you can just write `tagging.sh` instead of `/path/to/tagging.sh`